# The calculation of section height does not work as expected

Tags: html, css

The navbar should have a height of 90px, and the rest of the screen should have a height of 90vh, however `calc("100vh - 90px")` doesn't work.

I can't see the red section part

here is my html and css code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 90px;
}

.section1 {
  height: calc(~"100vh - 90px");
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu"></nav>
<div class="section1"></div>
```

I see only the purple navbar

Comment: you don't need the tilda or quotes - it should just be `height: calc(100vh - 90px);`

Comment: height: calc(100vh - 90px); should solve the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you are mixing [less](https://lesscss.org/#) [escape sequence](https://lesscss.org/#escaping) `~"..."` with regular CSS code. It dictates to use the enclosed string *as is* and not do any calculations.

`height: calc(~"100vh - 90px");` is less code and is not recognized by CSS.
Just change to `height: calc(100vh - 90px);`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 90px;
}

.section1 {
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu"></nav>
<div class="section1"></div>
```

Comment: @tatactic Neither do I.